# how do i get to a specific parent element depends on its child, and change its content - jquery?

Tags: jquery

well its a little bit complicated
i cant manage to find the right way to get this to work
ill explain it the best with some examples:
my generated nav look like this:

```
 <ul class='cat-nav'>
     <li class="c1">
        <h1>
           <a href="catalog.php?catid=8">main category 1</a>
        </h1>
     </li>
     <li class="c2">
        <h1>
           <a href="catalog.php?catid=9">main category 2</a>
        </h1>
           <ul class='subcat-nav'>
               <li>
                  <h1>
                     <a href="catalog.php?catid=7">main cat 2 - 1st subcat</a>
                  </h1>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <h1>
                     <a href="catalog.php?catid=19">main cat 2 - 2nd subcat</a>
                  </h1>
               </li>
           </ul>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

now what iam trying to do is to get to the li who has sub cats in it

(meaning has another ul inside)
and disable its link so the main cat will play only a title instead of an actual link.

i've tried the following with no success so far

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.cat-nav li').each(function() {    
    if($(this).children('ul').length == 1) {
    $('a').replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });  
    }
});
});
```

this script disables all the links in the ul.cat-nav, which is wrong for me...

Comment: A (hopefully) useful tip on asking for help on SO: reduce your code to the minimum necessary to understand and reproduce the problem and provide good feedback. Many of those `<li>` elems are basically the same, you can only include one of each type, for example.

Comment: thanks, i made it shorter....

Comment: $('a') selects all your a elements, you need to filter the ones you need to disable

Comment: Specify _a_ elements that you need properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jWmMK/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.subcat-nav').each(function() {  // start from subcat-nav  
        $(this).parent().find('h1:first a')
            .replaceWith(function() { // your code
                return $(this).contents();
            });

    });
});
```

Comment: that seems to be right. but what happens if i change the markup from <h1><a>link</a></h1> to <a><h1>link</h1></a> ?

Comment: @dada Change the selctors and use unwrap(). Check this fiddle for a full example. http://jsfiddle.net/jWmMK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Select the `.subcat-nav` directly, use [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) to target the `<h1>`, use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the child `<a>`, then call your function to make it only a title. See a full listing of [jQuery's DOM traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) techniques for more useful functions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.cat-nav li ul.subcat-nav')
        .siblings('h1')
        .find('a')
        .replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); }); 
});
```

Comment: @wirey In the second `<li>` the `<h1>` is a sibling of the inner `<ul>`; as for whether it's valid html, I don't know, but jQuery doesn't care too much about the HTML validating, and they are siblings in the DOM tree

Comment: siblings() retrieves a new jQuery object in the same scope/level of the current selector, so @nbrooks is correct.

Comment: @Ben Yes that's true...not sure what you're getting at. Take a careful look at the HTML for the second `<li>`...Oh okay, you're agreeing, no worries :D

Comment: @nbrooks thanks that works perfect, but when i think about it again..my html markup seems to me wrong.so i change the it from <h1><a>link</a></h1> to <a><h1>link</h1></a>, now it changes all...